# Inheritance Issues with instanceOf not recognised in IF condition

Tags: java, inheritance, instanceof, bluej

I have an the following inheritance hierarchy: Staff (Abstract), HomeWorker (Abstract), Typist. Typist inherits from both abstract classes.

I am implementing an interface called Manager (for an academic assignment). The class that I am implementing Manager in is called Branch. One of the methods in Branch that I need to implement is setEmail, shown below.

The issue is that only Typists have email addresses, not other Staff (Translators and Clerks). All staff are stored in a TreeMap . I'm trying to check that the staff member specified by the id parameter is an instanceOf Typist, before I try calling the setEmail method (as this method only exists on Typist).

However, using BlueJ, as soon as I type instanceOf in the IF condition, the scope highlighting is telling me it's out of scope and that ')' is required after the staffMember reference.

Any ideas??

```
/** Sets email for a typist

 * @param id represents the staff id
 * @param email is the email address
 */ 
public void setEmail(String id, String email)
{
    //Should be done in the typist class. This increases coupling though. 
    //Need to see if there is a way that I can do this using the staff class instead 
    Staff staffMember = staff.get (id);
    //TO DO: Need to put an IF statement in that confirms the staff member is a typist,    otherwise I could end up
    //trying to set an email against a staff type which doesn't store email addresses
    if (staffMember instanceOf Typist)
    {
    staffMember.setEmail(email);      
    }

}
```

Comment: `Typist inherits from both abstract classes.`  Not possible with java.

Comment: The keyword is `instanceof`, not `instanceOf`.

Comment: Sorry, it's in the hierarchy below the two classes - so Staff is top level, then HomeWorker is the next level. So typist only actually inherits directly from HomeWorker, though it has fields from Staff too, due to the hierarchy

Comment: have you already assured that `staffMember` is not null so the id is actually found within your staff-tree and the returned instance is actually a `Typist`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the keyword

`instanceof`

instead of

`instanceOf`

since this last one is not a keyword in Java.

Comment: +1 for the sharp eye and worth mentioning the `null instance of Typist` is  `false` :)

Comment: Indeed that was the case! Thanks, I wasn't seeing the wood for the trees there.

Comment: The problem was the syntax error. And good point about adding a check that the staff member does exist in the list, I was going to do this when I got the other bit working :-)